# How to properly say 'number of people'?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage, translation

**THE SITUATION:**

In an online form I need to know how many people book a service.

**EXAMPLE:**

Type of service - ...

Date - ...

Number of people - ...

**THE QUESTION:**

What is the proper way to ask it?

Is ***number of people*** correct?

Or should be perhaps ***amount of people***?

Is ***people number*** used?

Or in a different way?

Thank you!

Comment: "Number of people" is correct, though "number of customers" or some such might be better.

Comment: Thank you. If you write it as an answer I can mark it as correct

Comment: Depending of the service, "passengers", "guests", "attendees" or "participants" may fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Number of people.**

If it's a taxi service, you could say

*Number of passengers.*

If it's a restaurant, you could say

*Number of diners.*

Etc.

Answer (score -1):

You'd better to use such style : **Booked : __ times**.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks. But i need explicitly to ask how many people

Comment: -1. How many times something was booked is completely irrelevant to how many people are involved in a single booking. (And “you’d better to use…” is ungrammatical in English, too.)